# My Google Map Fusion Layer doesn't load when I add a new event?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a custom Google Maps Fusion Layer and I am trying to add a checkbox that once it is clicked will switch to a new Fusion Layer on the map.

However, when I add in a new Google Events DomListener to do this, not only does it not work but my original map now no longer loads and I cannot figure out why?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('houseChoropleth'),
  'click', function() {
  var houseMap = document.getElementById('houseChoropleth');
  layer.setOptions({
  query:{
  select: "col40>>0"",
  from: '16NkOpQVdCaNu8jo1Wvhk8x2LcXBXhyY4dPowkhQ' }
    });
    });

}
```

My current Javascript code can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/VD9LN/1/

I am using the sample code provided by Google here as a reference on how to implement it: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/heatmap

Though I changed the heatmap section so it generates my new Layer.

(the changeMap_0 function in my code is for my search bar and works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra " in your query:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('houseChoropleth'),
  'click', function() {
    var houseMap = document.getElementById('houseChoropleth');
    layer.setOptions({
      query:{
        select: "col40>>0"",
        from: '16NkOpQVdCaNu8jo1Wvhk8x2LcXBXhyY4dPowkhQ' 
      }
    });
  });

}
```

[this modified version works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/3gaFV/1/)

[with checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/3gaFV/2/)

Comment: Thanks very much for spotting that! 
Bit embarrassing to be foiled by that!

It works now but the original layer doesn't reload when I deselect the checkbox, though I thought this should happen?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there was a checkbox involved, you didn't include your HTML. You will need to look at the state of the checkbox and set the appropriate options inside the click function.  See the updated fiddle.

Comment: That's really great, I really appreciate your help! Everything is working now so I will be able to build on it, thanks again for taking the time to answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

is it just me, or do you have an extra " on the select: line

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('houseChoropleth'),'click', function() {
    var houseMap = document.getElementById('houseChoropleth');
    layer.setOptions({
        query:{
            select: "col40>>0"", <--------- ?
            from: '16NkOpQVdCaNu8jo1Wvhk8x2LcXBXhyY4dPowkhQ' }
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Ooft that's embarrassing! Thanks very much for spotting that, it's been driving me crazy! 
The map now works on the checkbox selection but it doesn't go back to the original map after it is deselected?

Comment: geocodezip seemes to have gotten it to work on jsfiddle :) (check the comment before mine)